# My url not reading my function in views.py in DJANGO (found similar question not able to trace my issue)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
urlpatterns = [
    url('update_db/(<dbname>)/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('mysite/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(),name='login'),
    url(r'^fetch/',include('polls.urls')),
    url('mysite/logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

polls.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
urlpatterns = [
    url('update_db/(?P<dbname>\w+)/$', login_required(views.MyView.get), name='x'),
    url('', login_required(views.IndexView.as_view())),
]
```

fetch.html

```
<td><a href="{% url 'x' dbname=schdule.5 %}/?next='fetch'">click</a></td>
```

polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView , ListView 
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Item , DbRestorationLogDetails
class MyView(UpdateView):
    logger.error('Something went wrong!')
    print "THANKS FOR UPDATING"
    template_name='fetch.html'
    model = DbRestorationLogDetails
    fields =['verification_status']
    def get(self,request, dbname):
        usname=request.user
        print usname
        print dbname
        if request.method == "GET":
            dblog = DbRestorationLogDetails.objects.get(dbname=dbname)
            dblog.verification_status = 'Verified'
            print dblog.verification_status
            dblog.save()
            #.update(dblogdetails.verification_status = 'Verified')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next'))
```

> > NOTE: NOT able to reach to MyView.get() and no db update happening. I assume my code is not able to read my function.

Comment: You are mixing `path(..)` syntax with `url(..)` syntax. The `update_db/(<dbname>)/` is missing a regex for `<dbname>`.

Comment: using django-admin.py version 1.11.16 .It says to use url instead of path

Comment: Yes but you have used path *syntax* in a url call.

Comment: please tell the right format